What is the criterion for a symmetric complex matrix to be orthogonal-diagonalisable?
For a symmetric matrix $M\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ to be orthogonal-diagonolizable, I mean that there exists $P\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that $PP^T=I$ and $PMP^T$ is diagonal.
Note that there exists symmetric matrix which is not orthogonal-diagonolizable, for example the symmetric nilpotent $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&i\\i&-1\end{pmatrix}$.
The question comes from the combination of the following results. Because of the counterexample, obvious generalisations fail.

If $M$ is symmetric and real, then $PMP^T$ is diagonal for some $P$ with $PP^T=I$;
If $M$ is Hermitian ($M=\overline M^T$), then $PMP^*$ is diagonal for some $P$ with $PP^*=I$.

If there are study concerning other base fields or rings, I am also interested.
